# How to pass data to custom mailer in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, mailer

I am using custom mailer to send confirmation email to user but I need to pass some data to the mailer. I have tried using session and application helper but no success.
Application helper is not able to access session data.
mailer is also not able to access session data.

This is my code

```
class CustomMailer < Devise::Mailer
  helper :application # gives access to all helpers defined within `application_helper`.
  include Devise::Controllers::UrlHelpers # Optional. eg. `confirmation_url`
  #include ApplicationHelper
  default template_path: 'devise/mailer' # to make sure that you mailer uses the devise views
def confirmation_instructions(record, token, opts={})
    opts[:subject] = "Email Confirmation"
    opts[:from] = 'no-reply@test.com'
end

end
```

I dont want to call custommailer from controller. I just want to pass data.

Is this possible?

Comment: Try this one :
https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/how-to:-use-custom-mailer

Comment: @sam did you ready my question?? I bet you had not read it.

Comment: What data are you trying to pass? And if you don't want to call `CustomMailer` from the controller, then where do you call it? (can you try to explain again maybe what exactly do you want to happen?)

Comment: @ZivGalili kindly check this question.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48868508/how-to-pass-extra-params-inside-option-hash-in-confirmation-email-in-rails/48869751#48869751