# How to pass extra params inside option hash in confirmation email in Rails?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, devise, mailer

I am trying to pass extra params inside the options{} hash in the confirmation email but It is just showing me subject and from headers in the mailer.
This is my code

```
CustomMailer.confirmation_instructions(user,token, {custom_param: "abc"})
```

When I show opts data inside template like this

```
@first_name = opts
```

It shows

```
{:subject=>"Email Confirmation", :from=>"no-reply@sample.com"}
```

custom mailer code is

```
class CustomMailer < Devise::Mailer
  helper :application # gives access to all helpers defined within `application_helper`.
  include Devise::Controllers::UrlHelpers # Optional. eg. `confirmation_url`
  #include ApplicationHelper
  default template_path: 'devise/mailer' # to make sure that you mailer uses the devise views

  def confirmation_instructions(record, token, opts={})
    opts[:subject] = "Email Confirmation"
    opts[:from] = 'no-reply@sample.com'

    if(record["admin"]==false)
        @template_type = 'donor'
        @first_name = opts

    end
end
```

why it is not working?

Comment: Can you paste your confirmation_instructions method please? In your CustomMailer

Comment: @mark yeah sure.I have edited the question. Please check it.

Comment: @Mark any idea?

Comment: From what I can see it should be taking the hash you give and adding the subject and from.. try '@opts' = opts as your first line and see if '@opts' gives you the required info in your mailer

Comment: And ignore the quotes - wouldn't let me post without them

Comment: @Mark no success. Still the same output. '@opts' = opts
still showing only subject and from.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165427/discussion-between-john-and-mark).

Answer (score 0):

Not a complete answer but the comments section was annoying me, try:

```
def confirmation_instructions(record, token, opts={})
  @opts = opts
  opts[:subject] = "Email Confirmation"
  opts[:from] = 'no-reply@sample.com'

  if(record["admin"]==false)
    @template_type = 'donor'
    @first_name = opts
  end
end
```

Then in your mailer, where you were calling @first_name, call @opts and it should give you the argument you feed into the method call.